# Seleccionar los 7 primeros elementos de un enum y mostrarlos en un Combobox mediante datasource

Tags: c#, .net, data, enum

Tengo un enum tal que,

```
public enum Region {
euw,
na,
br,
lan,
ru,
oce,
tr,
jap,
}
```

La cosa es que me gustaría mostrar los 7 primeros elementos, o lo que es lo mismo, todos menos el último.

Actualmente con

```
comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(RiotSharp.Misc.Region));
```

Puedo mostrar los 8 elementos en el comboBox, con el fin de mostrar los 7 primeros intenté lo siguiente:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(RiotSharp.Misc.Region)).Cast<RiotSharp.Misc.Region>().Where(ejemplo => 7 >= (int)ejemplo);
```

Pero me lanza el siguiente aviso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que estás usando Linq sólo agrega .ToList() al final

Así

```
comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Region)).Cast<Region>().Where(ejemplo => 7 >= (int)ejemplo).ToList();
```

Comment: Funciona a la perfección, ¡Gracias! :)

Comment: pero me temo que no termina de filtrar hasta el 7, aunque si carga la lista. Para filtrar correctamente tendrías que hacer algo así
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Region)).Cast<Region>().Where(x => (int)x <= 7).ToList();
        }
        public enum Region
        {
            euw=1,
            na=2,
            br=3,
            lan=4,
            ru=5,
            oce=6,
            tr=7,
            jap=8,
        }